# Setup MySQL replication - multiple machines?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

i read a lot of mysql server repliaction tutorials, but there's no hint, if the slave server is on a second machine or on the same server but just another mysqld process?

any advice?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the purpose of your setup. If you are doing it for higher availability (which should be), you need to use at least two machines. This is needed to lower the downtime when one server crashes. So, you can still run your applications using the other standing server.

If you are just experimenting, you can try running them on single machine.